# Which class is implementing ContextWrapper's methods in Android?

Tags: java, android, model, android-sdcard

While I'm developing Android-Apps I like to have a look at internal SDK implementations. It's a huge Framework and sometimes it helps a lot if you know, how internal Methods are implemented.

Now the last source-check I have done is really confusing to me. I looked at `Context` class to read some implementations. Unfortunately most of them are abstract, that's why Android invents the ContextWrapper, (a simple Adapter Pattern).

The problem is, that I couldn't find some Methods I'm interested in. Lets take `getResources` as Example. I have a ContextObject and call getResources on it. This Context is an instance of `Activity` (which is not implementing `getResources()` by itself).

Same for ContextThemeWrapper which is the direct parent-class of Activity. The ContextWrapper then invokes `getResources()` on its `Context` member. But who is implementing it then?

EDIT: added Snippet from ContextWrapper

```
public class ContextWrapper{
    Context mContext

    public ContextWrapper(Context ctx){
        mContext = ctx
    }

    public Resourced getResources(){
        return mContext.getResources()
    }

    //... all other Methods are implementing the same AdapterPattern
}
```

so the question can also be "which Context is passed to ContextWrapper, which is implementing required methods"

Comment: Have you tried invoking the method and then debugging your code?

Comment: if you attach the android source to the libraries, then it should be much easier to read and debug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found it out myself with the helpful tip from nicholas.hausschild, to just to run the debugger.

Unfortunatly this seems to be the only way, to find that out, because it's implemented in a Class called `ContextImpl`, which is package-readable (though not documented). You have to install Eclipse [source-code plugin](http://code.google.com/p/adt-addons/) (which seems to be a little buggy to install, if you had downloaded and linked the Android-SDK to eclipse  already) to see the sources.

For anyone who is interested in these sources: [clickme](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/app/ContextImpl.java)

Answer (score 2):

The `getResources()` method on the `Context` class is abstract, meaning whatever inherits from it needs to provide or override its implementation. The implementation of `getResources()` on the `ContextWrapper` class is concrete, and is where you should find its code.

Also, you have your inheritance chain a little backwards. `Activity` is a subclass of `ContextThemeWrapper`, not the other way around:

```
java.lang.Object
  ↳ android.content.Context              // abstract Resources getResources()
    ↳ android.content.ContextWrapper     // Resources getResources()
      ↳ android.view.ContextThemeWrapper // inherits ContextWrapper.getResources()
        ↳ android.app.Activity           // inherits ContextWrapper.getResources()
```

The [Android Developer Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) will help you with the inheritance structures.

Comment: you're right what you tell me about ContextThemeWrapper, but this is what I meant. I corrected the typo already. But the problem isn't solved by your answer: I mentioned that I know that ContextWrapper implementation of `getResources` is concrete. Have a look at my Edit to see, HOW it's implemented there